# counting elements for single person from excel sheet - vb .net

Tags: vb.net

I got the task and resolved it but I would like to find out if the code can be improved. I got the excel with many columns but only 2 of them are significant to me. One column respresents the people names and the second one, broker names. There are a few different brokers available and each person has been assigned to multiple brokers. The goal was to count the number of each brokers indenpendently for single person. Excel looks more/less like that:
Name1 Broker1
Name2 Broker2
Name3 Broker1
Name2 Broker1
Name2 Broker3
Name1 Broker3
Name3 Broker3

and so on. My code works fine and gives me the desired results. However i'm chasing the "perfection" in writing code so leave it to your evaluation if this could be shorten or improved. Thanks :)
osoby - people name
brokerzy - brokers name

```
Dim osoby As New List(Of String)
Dim brokerzy As New List(Of String)

For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            osoby.Add(row(1).ToString)
            brokerzy.Add(row(2).ToString)
Next

Dim osobyStr As String() = osoby.ToArray
Dim brokerzyStr As String() = brokerzy.ToArray



For Each osoba As String In osobyStr.Distinct()
            Dim brokerzy2 As New List(Of String)
            For i As Integer = 0 To osobyStr.Length - 1
                        If osobyStr(i).ToString = osoba Then
                                   brokerzy2.Add(brokerzyStr(i).ToString)
                        End If
            Next

            Dim brokerzyStrArr As String() = brokerzy2.ToArray
            Dim tes As String

            brokerzyStrArr.Distinct().ToList().ForEach(Sub(b) console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}:{2}",osoba,b,brokerzyStrArr.Count(Function(jeden) jeden=b)))
            console.readline()
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The code can be improved to some extent, of course. However, it may have a very little effect on performance.*

First things first. Let's minify a few lines. From:

```
Dim osoby As New List(Of String)
Dim brokerzy As New List(Of String)
```

To:

```
Dim osoby, brokerzy As New List(Of String)
```

The next thing that you are doing is looping through each `DataRow` in the `DataTable`. Instead, you can use a `DataReader`. The difference is that, when it comes to a `DataTable`, you need to first read the entire data(all rows) from a given database and store it in the `DataTable`, whereas in the case of a `DataReader`, you can access each row without having to wait for all the rows/records. Here's a sample :

```
Dim reader as OleDbDataReader = oledbCommand.ExecuteReader()
While reader.Read()
  Dim data = reader.GetString(1)
End While
```

Using a `DataReader` is ideal where performance is a priority. Another thing that you can do is run these database operations in the background, asynchronously. If you have a *WinForms* project, you can make use of the `BackgroundWorker` class and run the operation in background so that it doesn't affect your UI. If it's a class library or a different type of project, go with threading or regular async functions. Here are some references:

[BackgroundWorker Example](https://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker-vbnet)

[Asynchronous programming with Vb.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

The last `foreach` loop that you have, you can simplify it by using Linq. It may not improve performance, but it will make the code look cleaner and short. Here's a reference:

[LINQ with Vb.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/linq/introduction-to-linq)

Hopefully this helps you out!

Comment: Hi Zack, A reader holds the connection open so not a good choice if you want to mess around with the data. Load the DataTable with the speedy reader. Close the connection, then mess with the data.